# PHP - Update and Set aren't updating the database?

Tags: php, mysql, null, set

**SOLVED**

I had searched before asking this but found nothing, so I'll write here for anyone in the future. But to fix it all I had to do was make sure the $username was pointing to something, I had declared it in the login.php script but for some reason this wasn't finding it so setting $username=$_SESSION['myusername']; solved the problem.

---

In short I have a column called "Status" which is text, 140 characters. It's just a test to mess around with php so I can get used to it. Now at first it was updating the database but to null, I realized I hadn't set the post data to $status and after I did it was working, I updated the database twice and then it just stopped working... The page shows no errors but the value is stuck at the same thing it was the last time I changed it (uuu).

I have a form:

```
    <form action="status-update.php" method="post">
    <p>
  <input name="status" type="text" id="status" value="<?PHP echo $query_row[status]; ?>">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
    </p>
  </form>
```

Then when the button is pressed it takes you to this script:

```
<?php
SESSION_START();

//WAMP Login Details
$host = "localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$db_name="database";
$tbl_name="members";
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("Database doesn't exist.");

//Set $status to the post
$status=$_POST['status']; 

//This grabs the data from the form on the settings page and updates
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET status='$status' WHERE username='$username'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//if true then redirect else echo error
if($result){
header("location:me.php");
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

I tried to make it so it sets the value to null again but I can't even do that anymore which is strange, since I'm a noob I'm at a loss.

Comment: `value="<?PHP echo $query_row[status]; ?>">` -- XSS attack vector.

Comment: `UPDATE $tbl_name SET status='$status'` -- SQL injection attack vector.

Comment: I've managed to fix it, I put $username=$_SESSION['myusername']; after the WAMP Login Details and it's working now.

Comment: Is it correct that you are trying to update the user with username root? Because you're trying to update the username that you're using to connect with the database. Try echoing the $sql variable and disabling the header redirect to see what sql is being processed

Comment: First print the whole print_r($_POST), what's in it for $_POST['status'] and try to add die(mysql_error()) in your mysql_query() like like this:
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues.
First of all, it uses `mysql_` API whereas it is always said this API is over. As of PHP 5.5 it's even deprecated. So try to use mysqli or PDO.

Then you have to look out. Your sql query is vurnerable to injections as you do not escape properly your variables.

And how about trying to debug your code with the well known `or die(mysql_error());`next to your mysql_query call?

Answer (score 0):

Try using PDO, it's much less vulnerable to errors and attacks. Here is a basic update to your script using PDO:

```
<?php

// set PDO dsn by socket
$dsn = 'dbname=DATABASE_NAME;unix_socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock';

// or by tcp
$dsn2 = 'dbname=DATABASE_NAME;host=localhost;port=3306';

// create connection using sockets change $dsn to $dsn2 to use tcp if using windows or external host
$conn = new PDO('mysql:' . $dsn, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

// prepare query
$pdo = $conn->prepare("UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET status = :status WHERE username = :username");

// set up parameters
$params = ['username' => $_POST['username'], 'status' => $_POST['status']];

// loop through the paramaters to determine the type
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {

    switch ($value) {

        case is_int($value):
            $param = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            break;

        case is_bool($value):
            $param = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            break;

        case is_null($value):
            $param = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            break;

        default:
            $param = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            break;
    }

    // bind paramter to query
    $pdo->bindValue(":$key", $value, $param);
}

// execute the query
$result = $pdo->execute($params);

// if true then redirect else echo error
if ($result) {

    header("location:me.php");

} else {

    echo "ERROR";

}
```

You also don't need to end with `?>`, leave it off. It will save you having errors if you have whitespace after the closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

use session_start(); instead of SESSION_START();

Please make sure whether there is a **username** called **root** in your table!